# Query to get number of test passed for the latest day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I working on test tool, reporting for it.
SO, there is a test hich can be performed automatically several times per day. And In one report I need to show historical data per test (chart with Date and Number of test passed) and the number of passed tests for latest day.
Lef't create model of this issue:

I have such data structure (simplified):

```
DECLARE @TestResults TABLE
(
    TestId INT,
    DateOfResult DATE,
    TestPassedCount INT
);

INSERT INTO @TestResults VALUES (1,DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE()), 6);--This test passed 4 times  3 days ago
INSERT INTO @TestResults VALUES (1,DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()), 4); --This test passed 4 times yesterday
INSERT INTO @TestResults VALUES (1,GETDATE(), 5); --This test passed five times today

INSERT INTO @TestResults VALUES (2,DATEADD(day,-3,GETDATE()), 6);--This test passed 4 times  3 days ago
INSERT INTO @TestResults VALUES (2,DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()), 4); --This test passed 4 times yesterday

SELECT * FROM @TestResults;
```

Last select will return me a data set:

```
TestId   DateOfResult   TestPassedCount
1   2012-06-12             6
1   2012-06-14             4
1   2012-06-15             5
2   2012-06-12             6
2   2012-06-14             4
```

How can I also get with this query (in separate column) the number of passed tests for max available date? For example, for test with ID 1 I have data for 12,13,14 of June. So, in separate column I need to get 5 because on latest date (max(DateOfResults)) there is five passed tests?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thank you!

**Update:** I foound the way:

```
SELECT SubQ.*, r.TestPassedCount  FROM (
    SELECT *, Max(t.DateOfResult) OVER (PARTITION BY t.TestId ORDER BY t.TestId) as MaxDate FROM @TestResults t 
) AS SubQ JOIN @TestResults r ON r.TestId = SubQ.TestId AND r.DateOfResult = SubQ.MaxDate
```

Now I need to apply it to the real queries :) 
Are there any other ways to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't execute your solution, maybe are missing something? I'm having this error (and I can't figure why):

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
```

So, my version of the query is almost equal:

```
SELECT t2.TestId, t2.DateOfResult ,t2.TestPassedCount FROM @TestResults t2
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT t.TestId, MAX(t.DateOfResult) AS MaxDateOfResult from @TestResults t
            GROUP BY t.TestId ) groupedTests ON groupedTests.TestId = t2.TestId AND groupedTests.MaxDateOfResult = t2.DateOfResult
ORDER BY t2.TestId
```